# How to find out slack channel for my payload?

Tags: webhooks, slack, slack-api

I added webhooks

```
https://simple-web-app-space.slack.com/services/B04QWEH913B?added=1
```

My space is `simple-web-app-space`

I must add  `SLACK_CHANNEL=""` to my bash script

How to find out  which SLACK_CHANNEL I am on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out.
In Slack there is(after click on profile) Channel ID

[image]